# Script to bulk merge audio and a video+audio file

Tags: bash, video, ffmpeg, video-processing

I have a folder with 52 video+audio files (m3u8 extn)
and 52 audio files (different language)(m4a extn)
The names of the files are same
abcde.m3u8(video)
abcde.m4a(that other language audio only file)

i want to merge them so i have a single file Video+auido1+audio2
and i don't to lose any quality in the merging process

What would be the bash/ffmpeg command to do so?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Something like :

```
for f in *.m3u8
do
    basename="${f%.*}"
    ffmpeg -i "${basename}.m3u8" -i "${basename}.m4a" -c copy "${basename}.mkv"
done
```

Are you sure the `m3u8` files contain actual video frames?